# Retrieve X pixmap from CLI

Tags: linux, command-line, xorg

In a quest to figure out a way to dump the current wallpaper to a file, I've found the `_XROOTPMAP_ID` property on the root window. However, `xprop -root _XROOTPMAP_ID` only gives me something looking roughly like "pixmap id # 0xdeadbeef". Therefore, I've been wondering if there's a way to get at the contents of that pixmap without going through the effort of manually writing an application interacting with the X API.

EDIT: I have now written [xbgdump](https://github.com/FallenWarrior2k/xbgdump) for my specific use case. It's not the general solution I was asking for in this question, which is why I'll leave it open for now, but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt to similar situations.